# ¿Cómo descargar una imagen desde JS?

Tags: javascript, typescript

Cuento con la siguiente etiqueta:

```
             <img
              src={"enlace-imagen"}
              id="canvas"
              style={{
                objectFit: "scale-down",
              }}
            />
```

Por otro lado, tengo un botón con un evento onCLick que ejecuta la siguiente función:

```
   async function downloadImage() {

    const link = document.createElement("a");
    link.download = "codigoQR.png";
    let m = document.getElementById("canvas") as HTMLCanvasElement;
    link.href = m.toDataURL();
    link.click();
  }
```

El problema está en que al ejecutar la función, sucede la excepción: "m.toDataURL is not a function". Saben como solucionarlo?

Comment: Es TypeScript el código.

Comment: Revisaste todo en la consola del navegador? Sale algo cuando intentas hacer ese cast del img como canvas?

Comment: El único error que brinda la consola es: "payment_methods.tsx?fc4f:72 Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: m.toDataURL is not a function".  También da un erro 500 en el servidor interno, pero creo que es producto de la primera excepción.

Comment: Mi kung-fu en TS no es bueno, pero no veo en la [documentación](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLCanvasElement/toDataURL) que uno pueda hacer ese cast tan así nada más. Por eso la pregunta. Pero bueh, si llega alguien más pro que sepa la respuesta, veremos :)

Comment: Exactamente... ¿qué quieres hacer? Porque defines una imagen, la quieres usar como un canvas después de generar un enlace que apunta a un .PNG

Answer (score 0):

Tal como lo tienes diseñado:

```
 async function downloadImage() {
    const link = document.createElement("a");
    let m = document.getElementById("canvas") as HTMLImageElement;
    link.href = m.src;
    link.click();
}
```

Comment: Implementando tu solución, el navegador abre una nueva pestaña y muestra la imagen, no hace la opción de descarga. He investigado y creo que solo pasa en versiones antiguas del navegador.

Comment: A mi me abre una ventana de archivos para guardar la descarga. Supongo que dependerá del navegador.

Comment: Qué navegador estás usando?

Comment: Chrome Versión 104.0.5112.102 (Build oficial) (64 bits) (enriquegg.ddns.net/download)   <--- aquí una prueba online